# What's the difference between Series.sort() and Series.order()?

Tags: python, pandas

```
s = pd.Series( nr.randint( 0, 10, 5 ), index=nr.randint(0, 10, 5 ) )
s
```

Output

```
1    3
7    6
2    0
9    7
1    6
```

`order()` sorts by value and returns a new Series

```
s.order()
```

Output

```
2    0
1    3
7    6
1    6
9    7
```

It looks like `sort` also sorts by value, but in place:

```
s.sort()
s
```

Output

```
2    0
1    3
7    6
1    6
9    7
```

Is this the only difference between the two methods?

Comment: Did you read the docs? [pandas.Series.sort()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html#pandas.Series.sort) and [pandas.Series.order()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.order.html). It looks like `sort()` is there for compatibility with numpy.

Comment: I did read them . For `order()`, it is clearly written that it sorts by value and maintains index-value link. But for `sort()`, it just says "Sort values and index labels by value, in place". I thought this was confusing.

Comment: docs are better in 0.14/master (coming shortly). In ``Series.order(inplace=True) == Series.sort()``

Answer (score 12):

Your Question: Is this (*`Series.sort` in-place v.s. `Series.order` return-new-obj*) the only difference between the two methods?

### BEFORE pandas 0.17.0 Final release (i.e. before 2015-10-09)

Short Answer: YES. They are functionally equivalent.

Longer Answer:

[`pandas.Series.sort()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.Series.order.html#pandas.Series.order): change the object itself (in-place sorting), but returns nothing.

> Sort values and index labels by value. This is an *inplace sort* by default. **`Series.order` is the equivalent but returns a new Series.**

So

```
>>> s = pd.Series([3,4,0,3]).sort()
>>> s
```

outputs nothing. See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33572274/2303761) for more details.

[`pandas.Series.order()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html#pandas.Series.sort): dose not change the object, instead it returns a new sorted object.

> Sorts Series object, by value, maintaining index-value link. This will *return a new Series* by default. **`Series.sort` is the equivalent but as an inplace method.**

---

### AFTER pandas 0.17.0 Final release (i.e. after 2015-10-09)

The API of sorting is [changed](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api), things became cleaner and more pleasant.

To sort by the **values**, both `Series.sort()` and `Series.order()` are **DEPRECATED**, replaced by the new [**`Series.sort_values()`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values) api, which returns a sorted Series object.

To summary the changes (excerpt from pandas 0.17.0 [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api)):

```
To sort by the values (A * marks items that will show a FutureWarning):

        Previous              |         Replacement
------------------------------|-----------------------------------
* Series.order()              |  Series.sort_values()
* Series.sort()               |  Series.sort_values(inplace=True)
* DataFrame.sort(columns=...) |  DataFrame.sort_values(by=...)
```

Comment: I have been searching for a solution for hours. "inplace=True" is the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the pandas source code (and skipping out the docstring)

```
def sort(self, axis=0, ascending=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', inplace=True):
        return self.order(ascending=ascending,
                          kind=kind,
                          na_position=na_position,
                          inplace=inplace)
```

Compare this with the declaring line of order (I'm using 0.14.1)

```
def order(self, na_last=None, ascending=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', inplace=False)
```

You can see that since sort calls the order function the two are for all intents and purposes identical under the hood other than their default parameters.

As noted in the question, the default values of the `inplace` parameter for sort `inplace = True` and order `inplace = False` are different but there is no other difference in behaviour.

The other only other difference is that order has an additional (but deprecated) parameter in the form of `na_last` which you cannot use with sort (and shouldn't be using anyway).