# Why calling .sort() function on Pandas Series sorts its values in-place and returns nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Sorry I think I am missing something very basic here:

```
>>> Series([3,4,0,3]).sort()
```

outputs None, while

```
>>> Series([3,4,0,3]).order()
2    0
0    3
3    3
1    4
dtype: int64
```

what am I missing with sort()?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers, I do realize now that this is sorting in place. But I don't understand why

```
>>> s = Series([3,4,0,3]).sort()
>>> s
```

does not return the sorted Series. If I understand [the manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html) it should return the series sorted in place.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of the unanswered question [What's the difference between Series.sort() and Series.order()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23696834/974555).

Comment: Thanks, it didn't show up in the search result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.sort()` sorts *in-place*.

That means that after you call `.sort()`, your *existing array* has been sorted.  It doesn't return anything.

To take an example from "core" Python:

```
In [175]: L = [2, 3, 1, 5]

In [176]: L.sort()

In [177]: print(L)
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

It's the same for Pandas, as documented by [Pandas.sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html):

> Sort values and index labels by value, in place. For compatibility with ndarray API. No return value

See also: *[What's the difference between Series.sort() and Series.order()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23696834/974555)*

Comment: This solution is outdated for Pandas, see other answers.

Comment: Check my answer, it shows for latest version of Pandas about how to sort Series values in-place or create new Series object of sorted elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: s = pd.Series([3,4,0,3]).sort()
In [3]: s
```

Indeed `In [3]` will output nothing, as you can check:

```
In [4]: type(s)
Out[4]: NoneType
```

The reason:

`pd.Series([3,4,0,3])` indeed return a pandas `Series` type object, BUT `Series.sort()` method **return nothing** because of *inplace* sorting. So the expression `s = pd.Series([3,4,0,3]).sort()`, `s` in LHS get nothing from RHS, thus `In [3]: s` output nothing.

#### NOTE that:

After version **0.17.0**, sorting by **value** methods `pandas.Series.sort()` and `pandas.Series.order()` are DEPRECATED, replaced by a unified **`pandas.Series.sort_values()`** API. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696834/whats-the-difference-between-series-sort-and-series-order/33565542#33565542) for more details.

Comment: This answer is now more correct than the accepted answer. Under Pandas==0.22 Series.sort_values() is correct.

Answer (score 4):

> Both **.sort()** and **order()** functions are **DEPRECATED**
>   **.sort_values()** function is the replacement and here's the example on how to use it.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([1,3,4,2])
series = pd.Series(arr)
```

**Ascending Order**
Equivalent to .order() function from old versions.

```
ascending = series.sort_values()
```

**Descending Order**
Equivalent to .order(ascending=False)

```
descending = series.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

**In Place**
Equivalent to .sort() from old versions.

```
series.sort_values(inplace=True)
```

[For more info, check official documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 0):

As with most other python iterables, Series.sort() does actually return nothing but sorts the Series in place. See for example sorting a python list:

```
In [2]: foo = [5, 3, 9]

In [3]: foo.sort()

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: [3, 5, 9]
```